# Column-wise ordering of matrix

Tags: c++, r, sorting, rcpp, armadillo

I am new to *RcppArmadillo*. I am wondering how I can make a column-wise ordered matrix by the index of given vector. I know how to do it in *R*, but in RcppArmadillo it does not working. For example, in *R*,

```
aa = c(2,4,1,3)
# [1] 2 4 1 3
bb = cbind(c(1,5,4,2),c(3,1,0,8))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    5    1
# [3,]    4    0
# [4,]    2    8
```

Trying to subset with *R* gives:

```
cc = bb[aa,]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    5    1
# [2,]    2    8
# [3,]    1    3
# [4,]    4    0
```

I've tried the following using RcppArmadillo:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List example(arma::vec aa,arma::mat bb){

  int p = bb.n_rows;
  int n = aa.size();

  arma::uvec index_aa=sort_index(aa);;

  List cc(n);
  for(int it=0; it<p; it++){
    cc(it) = bb.each_col();
  }

  return List::create(cc);
}
```

and,

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List example(arma::vec aa,arma::mat bb){

  arma::uvec index_aa=sort_index(aa);

  return List::create(bb.elem(index_aa));
}
```

Comment: Show the expected output please.

Comment: I edited the question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are sorting the index here as that causes a new order to be introduced compared to `bb[aa,]`.

Anyway, the idea here is to subset using the [`.rows()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow) index, which requires a `uvec` or `unsigned integer` vector. As `aa` contains *R* indexes, we can translate them from *R* to *C++* by subtracting 1 to take it from a 1-based index system to a 0-based index system.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat example_subset(arma::uvec aa, arma::mat bb){

  // Convert to a C++ index from R (1 to 0-based indices)
  aa = aa - 1;

  return bb.rows(aa);
}
```

## Test code:

```
aa = c(2, 4, 1, 3)
bb = cbind(c(1, 5, 4, 2), c(3, 1, 0, 8))
cpp_cc = example_subset(aa, bb)
r_cc = cbind(c(5,2,1,4),c(1,8,3,0))
all.equal(cpp_cc, r_cc)
# [1] TRUE
```